# pass by value in recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Recursive solution for counting number of zeroes in a number is as below:

```js
    const number = 3004;
   
    const countZeroes = function (num) {
        if (num == 0) {
            return;
        }
    
        if (num % 10 == 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
    
        countZeroes(parseInt(num / 10));
    }
    
    let count = 0;
    countZeroes(3004);
    console.log('the result ', count);
```

The above solution works fine when we use count as a global variable. But it does not work when count is passed as a reference variable. Please find the solution below:

```js
    const number = 3004;
    
    const countZeroes = function (num, count) {
        if (num == 0) {
            return count;
        }
    
        if (num % 10 == 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
    
        countZeroes(parseInt(num / 10));
    }
    
    let count = 0;
    const result = countZeroes(3004, count);
    console.log('the result ', result);
```

Does javascript only allows pass by value and not by reference. Please let me know.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @ITgoldman All arguments are passed by value. Variables contain references to obejcts. This behavior is unrelated to the function call. You can observe the same behavior without functions, by copying objects. [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: You need to change the last line of the function to `return countZeroes(...)`

Comment: Technically yes, but if you pass by value a reference to an object (which object variables are) then effectively you pass the object by reference.

Comment: You're missing the second argument in the recursive call. It should be `return countZeroes(parseInt(num / 10), count);`

Comment: @ITgoldman The difference is, that you don't need a function call to observe this behavior. Your simplification doesn't describe the actual behavior and leads to confusion. `let a = {}; let b = a; b.a = 2`. No function call involved. `a` and `b` are modified.

Comment: The problems have nothing to do with pass by value or reference.